# Global paths conversions from WIndows to MACOS (R language example)

Tags: r, windows, macos, path

I tried to find some already existing solutions - no success so far.

**The problem**

There are some projects, all run in `R`, by a group of people, where each team member uses Windows as the main operating system.

Nearly each script file uses the following command at the very beginning

```
setwd("Z://00-00-00/path/to/project")
```

What is used here is some common disc space under the path `Z://00-00-00/`. Since I work on MAC OS my paths are `/common-drive/path/to/project` the question is:

Is there a way to include a command/script in some sort of file like `~/.bashrc` or maybe some `R`-related settings that will convert `Windows`-like absolute file paths to paths that are `MAC OS`-like when they detect it?

What I think should run is:

```
path.to.be.used <- "Z://00-00-00/path/to/project"
str_replace(path.to.be.used, "Z://00-00-00/", "/common-drive/")
```

however, all scripts have the path hard-coded directly in `setwd`, so I cannot change each file by hand. That is why I am trying to find out some workaround that will convert these paths in a "silent mode".

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Any way to make a control on system or R-studio level if the path should be converted?

Thank you for you time and help!

Comment: Depending on how you organise your projects, perhaps [here::here()](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here) might be useful

Comment: The suggestion is usually to [avoid setwd()](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/). It just doesn't make things reproducible. There `here` package suggestion is a good one or since you mention RStudio, use RStudio projects. Otherwise It's not clear how you are running these scripts, but you'd need to run some code to alter the default `setwd()` command and inject your own.

Comment: Thanks guys! I will try to convince them to change the policy of the projects. 
@MrFlick I use RStudio to run those scripts, so I thought that maybe somehow there is some sort of hack to tell RStudio to convert between paths. 
I think that so far user2554330 is the only way to do this and I need to remember to overload the command everytime before tunning any script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said in the comments, you should convince your co-workers not to do that.  However, that's often difficult, so here's a hack solution (mentioned by @MrFlick):

```
setwd <- function(dir) {
  newdir <- sub("Z://00-00-00/", "/common-drive/", dir)
  cat("Requested ", dir, ", using ", newdir, "\n")
  base::setwd(newdir)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought about. Do you know any way to run this by default when RStudio is opened? Something like on-init scripts ?

Comment: If you put that definition in `.Rprofile` then R will run it on startup.  R looks for this in the current directory first, then in the user's home directory.